# Websocket VP9 Videostream based on messages

Tags: websocket, video-streaming, html5-video, ratchet

I want to establish a video stream between a C# application and a Browser.
Im using Websockets for the communication.
The Video source is a webcam.

I am able to request single PNG frames but it is slow as hell.

The websocket Server(ratchet) is message based but is it possible to use VP9 compression or something similar by using some kind of buffer?

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets implement a messaging protocol over sockets. This is not desirable for video. I think a better suited technology for this is [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org).

Comment: Yes it absolutely is! The Problem, as far as I know, is that there is no free .Net implementation which can be used with C# yet.